# Cause of the light curtain after big Bang?

Tags: visible-light, big-bang

In the current model of the big bang there is a short phase of some minutes, where all the light in the universe was trapped. Which mechanisms were able to disable the expansion of light in this phase? Did neutrinos play a part in this, even though they do not interact with light?

Comment: Can you provide a citation for the existence of a _light curtain_ a few minutes after the Big Bang? This is not a term I have heard before. Are you sure you are not thinking of [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology))?

Comment: That "short moment" lasted approx. 300,000 years, or so. That's how long it took for the expansion to cool the hydrogen gas below its ionization temperature of 7000K. Above 10,000K the gas is in the plasma state with free electrons and free protons. The plasma is electrically conductive and shields electromagnetic waves, including visible light. The neutral gas does not and light can pass. Weinberg should have titled his book "The first 300,000 Years" instead of "The first Three Minutes", but that doesn't sound good, does it?

Answer (score 3):

During its first $370,000$ years (known as the [photon epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_epoch)) the energy of the universe was dominated by photons. However, these photons could not travel very far because the temperature of the universe was so high that everything in it was ionised into a plasma of electrons and protons. Once a photon was emitted it would be almost immediately scattered or absorbed by an electron or a proton. As a result the universe was opaque to photons - in the same way as the body of the sun is opaque, and the light that we see from the sun consists of photons emitted from a thin and relatively cool layer near the surface of the sun called the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere).

After $370,000$ years the universe was cool enough to allow electrons and protons (and neutrons) to combine into hydrogen and helium atoms. Since these atoms were neutral, they did not interact so readily with photons, so the universe became (more or less) transparent.

Neutrinos did not play a part in this. Since neutrinos are neutral particles, they did not interact with the free electrons and protons during the photon epoch. In fact, neutrinos created soon after the Big Bang ceased to interact with other types of matter much earlier, about $1$ second after the Big Bang, in an event known as [neutrino decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_decoupling).

Comment: My expertise in this is having lunch with Willy Fowler, so I could be wrong: paragraph 2 implies (somewhat) that BB nucleosynthesis occurred during the last-scattering epoch...but the protons and neutrons had already formed helium nuclei, and the itty bitty amount of lithium. Though a web search failed to give me timestamps on BBNS, just after QGP....I guess it did overlap with the photon epoch?

Comment: Issue with the first sentence: radiation only constituted the majority of the energy density until about 50000 years, and photons themselves only until around 6000 years (the time that matter + neutrinos exceeds photons, since neutrinos contribute 41% of the radiation energy density).